# Order By Clause not working in SQL Server for Sorting date value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have two tables one is called Shelf Table which has the Shelf Number

| SEQ | SHELF_NUMBER | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID001 | 100 |
| 2 | ID002 | 20 |
| 3 | ID003 | 55 |
| 4 | ID004 | 200 |
| 5 | ID005 | 38 |

And the Other Table that i have is Shelf_Data

| SEQ | SHELF_NUMBER_FK | FIELD | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID001 | BATCH | 100006 |
| 2 | ID001 | SHELF_DATE | 08/20/2023 |
| 3 | ID002 | BATCH | 110009 |
| 4 | ID003 | BATCH | 565644 |
| 5 | ID003 | SHELF_DATE | 02/10/2024 |
| 6 | ID004 | BATCH | 222389 |
| 7 | ID004 | SHELF_DATE | 10/25/2023 |
| 8 | ID005 | BATCH | 181865 |

I have written a query for sorting based on the SHELF_DATE as below

```sql
SELECT s.SHELF_NUMBER, SUM(s.QUANTITY), sd.VALUE AS BATCH
  FROM SHELF s
  LEFT JOIN SHELF_DATA sd
    ON s.SHELF_NUMBER = sd.SHELF_NUMBER_FK
   AND sd.FIELD IN ('BATCH')
 WHERE s.QUANTITY > 0
 GROUP BY s.SHELF_NUMBER, sd.VALUE
 ORDER BY (CASE
            WHEN sd.FIELD = 'SHELF_DATE' THEN
             sd.VALUE
           END) ASC
```

**So, what I am trying to accomplish from above query is to get the shelf batch numbers with Valid quantity which are sorted by the SHELF Date in ascending order.
But the Order By Clause is not sorting the data with the Shelf_Date Value.**

**Desired Output::**

| SHELF_NUMBER | SUM_QUANTITY | BATCH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID001 | 100 | 100006 |
| ID004 | 200 | 222389 |
| ID003 | 55 | 565644 |
| ID002 | 20 | 110009 |
| ID005 | 38 | 181865 |

Really stuck here.. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you post your desired output?

Comment: Please also show current query result and the required result

Comment: Currently the query looks like pulling the data based on date but is not in any order.

Comment: Your `ORDER BY` is useless as the only `sd.FIELD` selected is 'BATCH' as specified in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Ok.. But i need to show the batches which have shelf life expiring earlier. If i don't put that clause on Batch then i get the Shelf Number twice, one for Shelf Date and one for Batch. So, essentially stuck here.

Comment: You could use e.g. `MAX(sd.FIELD)` in the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided (SHELF_NUMBER_FK, FIELD) is a unique key of the SHELF_DATA table you can join it twice. Not sure which date you want when grouping, assuming max.

```
SELECT s.SHELF_NUMBER, SUM(s.QUANTITY), sd1.VALUE AS BATCH, max(Convert(DATE, sd2.VALUE, 101) s_date
  FROM SHELF s
  LEFT JOIN SHELF_DATA sd1
    ON s.SHELF_NUMBER = sd1.SHELF_NUMBER_FK
   AND sd1.FIELD ='BATCH'
  LEFT JOIN SHELF_DATA sd2
    ON s.SHELF_NUMBER = sd2.SHELF_NUMBER_FK
   AND sd2.FIELD IN ='SHELF_DATE' 
 WHERE s.QUANTITY > 0
 GROUP BY s.SHELF_NUMBER, sd1.VALUE
 ORDER BY max(Convert(DATE, sd2.VALUE, 101)) ASC
```

Comment: I would of used CTE's but this works

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as 2 separate queries.

```
;with cte as 
(SELECT s.SHELF_NUMBER, SUM(s.QUANTITY) qty, sd.VALUE AS BATCH
  FROM SHELF s
  LEFT JOIN SHELF_DATA sd
    ON s.SHELF_NUMBER = sd.SHELF_NUMBER_FK
   AND sd.FIELD IN ('BATCH')
 WHERE s.QUANTITY > 0
 GROUP BY s.SHELF_NUMBER, sd.VALUE
)
select c.* from cte c
inner join SHELF_DATA sd
ON s.SHELF_NUMBER = sd.SHELF_NUMBER_FK
where sd.FIELD = 'shelf_date'
order by sd.value
```

Comment: if you have multiple dates for a shelf this may duplicate rows

Comment: @RegBes Having multiple dates for a single shelf doesn't make any sense to order it based on the date and moreover the OP did not mention anything regarding the multiple dates for single shelf